# PHPunit failed asserting exception is thrown

Tags: php, phpunit

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    try {
        $house = $this->createHouseFromType($data[self::KEY_TYPE]);
        $house->setValue($data[self::KEY_VALUE]);
        $house->setNewBuild($data[self::KEY_NEW_BUILD] == self::NEW_BUILD_INDICATOR);
        $house->setHitPoints($this->hitPointCalculator->calculate($house));

        return $house;
    } catch(RejectedProperty $exception) {
        return false;
    }
}

private function createHouseFromType($type)
{
    switch($type) {
        case self::DETACHED_INDICATOR:
            return new \DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\Detached();
        case self::SEMI_DETACHED_INDICATOR:
            return new \DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\SemiDetached();
        case self::TERRACE_INDICATOR:
            return new \DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\Terrace();
        default:
            throw new RejectedProperty();
    }
}
```

And the test itself

```
public function test_throwsRejectedPropertyExceptionIfCannotAllocateType()
{
    $data = [
        0 => null,
        1 => 100000,
        2 => null,
        3 => 'HU13 9LL',
        4 => null,
        5 => 'Y'
    ];

    $this->createObject()->create($data);
    $this->expectException(RejectedProperty::class);
}
```

I can't see any reason why this would fail, it's running

```
   default:
        throw new RejectedProperty();
```

The error

```
1)     DataAccess\CSV\House\Factory_Test::test_throwsRejectedPropertyExceptionIfCannotAllocateType
```

Failed asserting that exception of type "DataAccess\CSV\House\RejectedProperty" is thrown.

Comment: 1. Use 'Exception' in trailing exception class name. Ex. `class RejectedPropertyException`.

2. `public function create()` return false on exception, but not exception itself. Change `return false` to `throw $exception`